# parseInt('1e1') vs parseFloat('1e1')

Tags: javascript, parseint, parsefloat

```
parseInt(1e1); //10
parseInt('1e1'); //1
parserFloat('1e1') //10
```

Why parseInt returns 1 in the second case? The three shouldn't return the same result?

Comment: 1e1 is not a valid int. I guess it discards e1.

Comment: If you parseint(string), it will only read the first numeric portion of the string and the rest is discarded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `1e1` is a number literal that evaluates to `10`; `parseInt()` sees `10` and happily returns that.
2. `'1e1'` is a string, and `parseInt()` does not recognize exponential notation, so it stops at the first letter.
3. `'1e1'` as a string is perfectly fine when parsed as a float.

**Bonus**: `parseInt('1e1', 16)` returns `481`, parsing it as a 3-digit hex number.

Answer (score 1):

When you're trying to parse a string, only the first number in a string is returned. Check function specification at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Also, you can test it out yourself:
`parseInt('2e1')` - returns `2`
`parseInt('3e2')` - returns `3`

Comment: Do not recommend using w3schools.

Comment: why, @djechlin?

Comment: ok, already understood why: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com

Answer (score 0):

To understand the difference we have to read ecma official documentation for [parseInt](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.2/) and [parseFloat](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.3)

... **parseInt** may interpret only a leading portion of string as an **integer value**; it ignores any characters that cannot be interpreted as part of the notation of an **integer**, and no indication is given that any such characters were ignored...

... **parseFloat** may interpret only a leading portion of string as a **Number value**; it ignores any characters that cannot be interpreted as part of the notation of an **decimal literal**, and no indication is given that any such characters were ignored...

parseInt expects ONLY an integer value (1, 10, 28 and etc), but parseFloat expects Number. So, string `"1e1"` will be automatically converted to Number in parseFloat.

```
parseInt('1e1'); // 1

parseFloat('1e1'); // 10
```